# Pass array of objects to a data object in Vue specs

Tags: vue.js, axios, jestjs, specs

I am writing specs for my vue component and have to pass a value to a data object defined in the component
I am passing it like this,
`wrapper.vm.organizations = [{"id":2,"company_name":"google","user_count":0}]`

But in my component it is getting undefined and on console.log this is what i get,

```
[
      {
        id: [Getter/Setter],
        company_name: [Getter/Setter],
        user_count: [Getter/Setter]
      }
]
```

How can i pass values properly?

Answer (score 0):

The data property of an object represents its internal state and it is kind of weird to try to assign values from outside.

I would suggest to use properties (props). Props are values send from the outside to the component.

If properties doesn't work for you, then you could make a method in your component, that method will receive your new values and assign those values to internal data. From the outside instead of assigning directly the values, you will call a method to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Vue 3 wraps reactive data in [proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy). Therefore your data might look like this, with getters and setters.

Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(YOUR_ARRAY))` to see if your data is as expected.

You did not provide enough code, to know exactly why your data is `undefined`, where you expect it to be available.

Rememeber that props should be accessed using `this.$props.PROPNAME` inside a child component.